# Cannot delete Single Sign-on Settings

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Under Administration Setup - Security Controls - Single Sign-On Settings, I need to turn off Federated Single Sign-On Using SAML. However, whenever I disable the SAML Enabled checkbox and click [Save], I get the following error:

Error: Your organization or community is currently using SAML as an authentication method, so you can’t disable it.

Under Domain Management - My Domain, I've changed the Authentication Service setting to Login Page. Yet I keep getting the above error. How do I completely disable SAML for this Sandbox?

Comment: Do you have a community or portal?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but this is in a Sandbox environment.

Comment: Do you have a community or portal activated? Those can use the SAML settings as well, so you would not be able to turn it off if you are still using them.

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie when it comes to SFDC.  How would I know if I have a community or a portal activated?

Comment: In the setup menu Customize>Communities >All Communities for Communities and Customize>Customer Portal or Customize>Parter Portal for portal.

Comment: I don't have a Customize > Communities option under setup.

Comment: Ok, so you dont have communities then. Did you have portals?

Comment: Not that I can see.  I don't see a "Portals" option under Customize.  Nothing comes up when I put "portal" into the setup search.

Answer (score 5):

If you are unable to delete SAML Single Sign-On Settings in Salesforce, check the below before deleting it.

1. Go to Domain Management --> My Domain. Check whether the SAML Settings is disabled in "Authentication Configuration" section. If not, please disable it.
2. Please check the Portal Login and Registration Settings and Community Login and Registration Settings and do the same.

Answer (score 2):

this is a known issue with no fix: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000sY1bAAE